# django forms from two tables referencial integrity

Tags: django, integrity, modelform, foreign-keys

i have a class named **cv**,and a class named **university**, and each user that completes his cv, should choose a University he studyes at.

My problem is: one student can study at one or 2 or three universities, or may be a user that is not student.

I need to take this data into a form, and i use ModelForm. The data from the Cv class, and from the University class in the same form, and the user can add one or more universities, or no university. (in the same form)

How should i do it? Should i use ModelForm? if i have a foreign key in the CV class, and the user is not a student (so he is at zero universities), i may get an referencial integrity error.

thanks a lot

Comment: First, why don't  you have a proper many-to-many relationship between the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelForms` will display your `ManyToManyField`s (that's the correct type for your `university` field in your `Cv` class) as multipe-select widget.

If you prefer checkboxes, use the `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget for this field in your form class.